# How to change marker size with pandas.plot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a chart created from `df.plot(style="o")` where the `o` markers are too big. Would it be possible to size them down?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(1, 10))
df.plot(style="o")
```

[image: plot where markers are too big]

How can I shrink them down?

Comment: A quick fix: you can use df.plot(style=".") instead!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

After investigation, it looks like that you can pass the `ms`, short for `markersize` (which also work) argument directly to `pandas.plot()`  such has:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(1, 10))
df.plot(style="o", ms=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `markersize` instead of `ms`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest there is a 2 days restriction before accepting your own answer.

Comment: True, my fault, sorry.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Pandas 1.2 for a `df.plot.scatter(...)`: `'PathCollection' object has no property 'markersize'`

Comment: `df.plot.scatter(s=1000)` works to set `markersize` in scatter plots.

Comment: I want to set size based on column values but multiplied by a constant factor since the default markers are too small. Anyone know if `df.plot.scatter(s="size")` has a marker size scaling factor argument?