# Create histogram from panda frame

Tags: python, histogram

I am trying to created bar histogram that will show the mean of subjects by groups

my data looks like this -

> ```
>      week     8    exp                          
>    Subject Group      1      2      3        Mean
> 0      255  WT 0  101.8   75.6   84.1   87.166667
> 1      157  HD 0   92.6   87.8   82.3   87.566667
> 2      418  WT 0   54.5   47.0   50.8   50.766667
> 3      300  WT 0   48.1   73.1   72.2   64.466667
> 4      299  HD 0   71.8   86.0   93.4   83.733333
> 5      258  WT 0   88.0   98.5   50.2   78.900000
> 6      173  WT 0   75.4   70.5   83.9   76.600000
> 7      273  HD 0  103.6   94.2  108.3  102.033333
> 8      175  WT 0   36.7   30.7   42.2   36.533333
> 9      172  HD 0   82.6   91.6   73.4   82.533333
> 10     263  WT 0  110.7  102.4  105.5  106.200000
> 11     304     1   90.4   90.1  103.4   94.633333
> 12     305     1  128.6  141.5  123.1  131.066667
> 13     306     1   52.0   45.6   57.2   51.600000
> 14     309   0.1   41.3   52.6   79.9   57.933333
> 15     317   0.1   86.2   95.8   77.1   86.366667
> ```

My code is -

```
frame_data = pd.read_csv('final results.csv', header=[0,1])

data_avg = df.iloc[:, -3:].mean(axis=1)

frame_data[('exp', 'Mean')] = frame_data.iloc[:, -3:].mean(axis=1)

grouped_by_group = frame_data.groupby(['Group', 
'Mean']).size().unstack('Mean')

grouped_by_group.plot.bar(title='Grip')
```

I am getting an error 
KeyError: 'Group'

i checked many times and it is the way it is written... I do not know what is wrong...

Comment: `Group` doesn't exist in the context you have selected, which is why you get a `KeyError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think need reshape `DataFrame` by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), aggregate `mean` and then then [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
frame_data = pd.read_csv('final results.csv', header=[0,1])
frame_data[('exp', 'Mean')] = frame_data.iloc[:, -3:].mean(axis=1)

#flatten MultiIndex to columns 
frame_data.columns = frame_data.columns.map('_'.join)

grouped_by_group = frame_data.groupby('8_Group')['exp_Mean'].mean()
print (grouped_by_group)
8_Group
0.1     72.150000
1       92.433333
HD 0    88.966667
WT 0    71.519048
Name: value, dtype: float64

grouped_by_group.plot.bar(title='Grip')
```

Comment: while running 
      grouped_by_group = frame_data.groupby([('12','Group'), 
    ('exp','Mean')]).size().unstack()

I am getting an error
    ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (16,) (2,)

Comment: ok after getting an heart attack from the new shape it does able to make an histogram.
but, it puted every subject in it own bar and not by average of the 4 groups

Comment: ok. now i get bars for each group for each subject.
what i need is for each  group one bar, that holds the average of the subject of the group...
i was trying to do that by grouping but it doesnt seems to be enough

Comment: The groups are 0 WT, 0 HD, o.1 and 1.
So i need 4 bars in the graph at the end. The bar of 1 for example should be the average of the means of subjects 304, 305,306

Comment: Basicly the Mean column is the average of the other 3

Comment: @TalyaShacham -  I think need aggregate means per groups by column `8_Group`, check edited answer.

Comment: If you dont mind me to ask.
is there anyway to add STD to this graph or statistical analyzing to the different of the groups?
I know how to do both on simple arrays but this one is a bit complicate for me at this point, i am still studying.

Comment: No problem, need `grouped_by_group = frame_data.groupby('8_Group')['exp_Mean'].agg(['mean','std'])`

Comment: this add it as another bar not as std line on the avg bars

Comment: @TalyaShacham - Check [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#plotting-with-error-bars), so need `gp3 = frame_data.groupby('8_Group')['exp_Mean']`, then `means = gp3.mean()  
errors = gp3.std()` and last `fig, ax = plt.subplots() means.plot.bar(yerr=errors, ax=ax)`

Comment: any chance you know how to make a dot plot with the same data?

Comment: @TalyaShacham - Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41107386/2901002) ?

Comment: i mean this
https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html
but i dont manage to fit my data in

Comment: Not so easy, maybe best is create new question.