# Adding legends to scatter plot (panda & matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

**Hi, everybody !**

I need to plot a scatter graph thanks to an excel(.xlsx) by using panda and matplotlib.

Basically, this excel has 4 columns (A, B, C and D)  and many rows. I would like to be able to create a scatter plot with 2 legends (one that will highlight a size difference according to the values of a column and a color difference thanks to a colorbar according to the values of another function). The 4 different components, corresponding to the 4 columns, will thus have to be grouped together in the graph.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import latex
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

df.plot.scatter(x = 'A [-]', y = 'B [-]', c='C [Pa]', cmap='viridis', legend=True)
 
plt.show()
```

Finally, only thing left I have to do: plot the column of D values characterized by a difference in point size. I tried something like this but I don't know how to add the column D:

```
h = [plt.plot([],[], color="gray", marker="o", ms=i, ls="")[0] for i in range(1,10, 2) 

plt.legend(handles=h, labels=range(50,250,50), title="D")
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Output:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(5)
s = np.array(([10,30,50,70,90]))
ax.scatter(x,y, s=s)

handles = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=i+1) for i in range(5)]
plt.legend(handles, s)
```

Output:

[image]

----edit----

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
s = np.arange(10)*10+1
c = np.arange(10)
# fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot = ax.scatter(x,y,c=c, s=s)
# fig.colorbar(plot)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': x, 'B': y, 'C': c, 'D': s})
df.plot.scatter('A', 'B', c='C', s=df['D'])
handles = [Line2D([0], [0], color='k', linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=s[i]/10) for i in range(len(s))]
plt.legend(handles, (s-1)/10)
```

Output:

[image]

------ edit again -------

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.random(100)
s = np.arange(100)
c = np.arange(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': x, 'B': y, 'C': c, 'D': s, 'D_grouped': s//10})

actualD = []
for i in range(len(df['D'])):
    if df['D_grouped'][i] not in actualD:
        actualD.append(df['D_grouped'][i])

labelD = []
for j in range(len(actualD)):
    labelD.append(f'{actualD[j] * 10} - {(actualD[j]+1) * 10-1}')

actualD = np.array(actualD)
labelD = np.array(labelD)

df.plot.scatter('A', 'B', c='C', s=df['D_grouped']*10, cmap='jet')
handles = [Line2D([0], [0], color='k', linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=actualD[i]) for i in range(len(actualD))]
plt.legend(handles, labelD)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Exactly, however I don't know how to incorporate the values of the column D to the legend (accordingly to the scatter plot). I just added my output. Thank you.

Comment: I you insist o using pandas plot you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107232/how-to-change-marker-size-with-pandas-plot/41107386 , otherwise with matplotlib it works like this ``ax.scatter(x,y, s=s)`` as I wrote in the code above

Comment: What I really need here is to make the marker size change **accordingly** to the values of the D column and then to plot a legend related to this. In fact, the "i in range(x,x,x)" is wrong and was just an example.

Comment: if I change my code above from ``handles = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=i+1) for i in range(5)]`` to ``handles = [Line2D([0], [0], color='b', linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=s[i]/10) for i in range(5)]`` I will have the same result. and I just want to emphasize that it will work in the case of ``plt.plot``, as I never worked with ``df.plot``, I can't be sure to say that it will work as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, indeed, I need to use panda, and then 'df.plot', to extract the data from the excel to then plot it. I will wait for another answer, thank you for your time !

Comment: see my edit, I made the ``df.plot`` version

Comment: The code here success to change the size of the different point according to the values of the column D thanks to your code ! However, the legend doesn't want to establish any label. Is it possible to decompose the set of values in column D into a maximum of 4 points in accordance with the size of the points relative to the values in column D already plotted ? In fact, I have around 200 rows so I can't plot all the points in the legend like you did in your scatter plot. 

The problematic code is this one: 
`plt.legend(handles, (s-1)/10, title="D", loc="lower right")`

Comment: what do you mean by ``decompose the set of values in column D into a maximum of 4 points in accordance with the size of the points relative to the values in column D already plotted``? have a range instead of one single number? like 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 and so on?

Comment: Exactly, the values are in the following range: [40, 180]. So, if it is possible, have a legend with increasing size points with points for the values 40, 75, 110, 145 and 180. In fact, the exact same legend as yours but only with some points and not all of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the Line2D function here (maybe because of the fact that I am using an excel sheet ?), that's why I was trying to code with this one: `h = [plt.plot([],[], color......`

Comment: it has nothing to do with the excel sheet. you are using pandas dataframe as well. Well, it's getting too long. if you want me to try it further then provide me your actual dataframe or at least made up a fake dataframe.

Comment: add ``from matplotlib.lines import Line2D``. you can't use the Line2D function since you haven't imported it yet. I added all the import that I use in the code above